# Get Azure Databricks URL using Terrafrom

Tags: azure, terraform, databricks, azure-rm-template, terraform-provider-azure

In Dev environment, I deploy Azure DataBricks using Terrafrom and can get the URL using workspace_url https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/databricks_workspace.html. But in production, I have to deploy the entire infrastructure through terraform and only Azure Databricks through ARM (this is the company's policy). ut when I use data.azurerm_databricks_workspace.example, for example, I get an error that there is no way to use azurerm_databricks_workspace in data. Tell me how can I get workspace_url and use it in Terrafrom. Thanks.

Comment: can you show how you use it?data.azurerm_databricks_workspace contains workspace url: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/databricks_workspace#workspace_url

Answer (score 1):

When going through sources of [Databricks Labs Terraform](https://databricks.com/blog/2020/09/11/announcing-databricks-labs-terraform-integration-on-aws-and-azure.html) provider, you can find reference to [workspace properties endpoint](https://github.com/databrickslabs/terraform-provider-databricks/blob/d5ff76980ece4bfb49f2ef263d0c1584cb768a9a/common/azure_auth.go#L218), which would have `workspaceUrl` in `properties` field. So if you call `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<uui>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces/<workspace-name>` with management AAD JWT token, you should be able to retrieve workspace URL.

I'm not sure if it's exposed to ARM Templates, though Azure CLI [does expose it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/scenarios/quickstart-create-databricks-workspace-resource-manager-template#azure-cli-1).